# React Native - Using Firebase to Upload an Image

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, firebase-storage

I am using expo and I have been trying to upload a local image from the camera or gallery using [expo-image-picker](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/) to firebase. This is my code so far:

```
const uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();
    var ref = firebase
      .storage()
      .ref()
      .child("images/" + imageName);
    console.log(ref);
    return ref.put(blob);   };

  uploadImage(uri, "Test_image");
```

I keep getting this error message:

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
FirebaseStorageError {
  "code_": "storage/unauthorized",
  "message_": "Firebase Storage: User does not have permission to access 'images/Test_image'.",
  "name_": "FirebaseError",
  "serverResponse_": "{
  \"error\": {
    \"code\": 403,
    \"message\": \"Permission denied. Could not perform this operation\"
  }
}",
}
```

Comment: Is it the security rules that are blocking?

Comment: Try following [Get Started section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start) and "During development, consider setting up your rules for public access".

Comment: Ah yes thank you! I forgot to change the rules to public. It works perfectly now.